# Passing two model values to different form.blade under one view in laravel 5.1 for edit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In my edit.blade page I have include two form blades as given below. To update I have to pass two different model data for those blades but its not working in my way. Please help me.

Here is my edit blade:

```
{!! Form::model($requisitions, array('route' => ['requisition.update', Crypt::encrypt($requisitions->id)], 'id' => 'requisition_update', 'class' => 'form-horizontal row-border')) !!}
                @include('department_user.requisitions._form')
                 <div style="height:30px;"></div>
                    <h4> Requisition Material(s) </h4>
                    @include('department_user.requisitions._item_form')
                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                    {!! Form::label('', '', array('class' => 'col-md-2 control-label')) !!}
                    {!! Form:: submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
                </div>
            {!!form::close()!!}
```

and my function is

```
public function edit( $id ) {
        $id = Crypt::decrypt($id);
        $requisitions = Requisition::findOrFail($id);
        $requisitionitems = RequisitionItem::findOrFail($id);
        $chargeable_accounts    = [''=> 'Select Chargeable Account'] + ChargeableAccount::whereStatus(1)->orderBy('name', 'DESC')->lists('name', 'id')->toArray();

        $item_measurements    = [''=> 'Select Item'] + ItemMeasurement::whereStatus(1)->orderBy('item_name', 'DESC')->lists('item_name', 'id')->toArray();

        $units    = ['' => 'Select Unit'] + MeasurementUnit::whereStatus(1)->orderBy('name', 'DESC')->lists('name', 'id')->toArray();
        return view('department_user.requisitions.edit', compact('units', 'item_measurements', 'chargeable_accounts', 'requisitions','requisitionitems'));
    }
```

Comment: You are calling form::close() instead of Form::close()

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to the include just use a second parameter

```
@include('department_user.requisitions._item_form', $modelA)
@include('department_user.requisitions._item_form', $modelB)
```

This should do the trick. Also:

```
{!!form::close()!!}
```

to

```
{!!Form::close()!!}
```